# Windows update source keeps changing

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain

I recently disconnected a Windows 7 computer from a company network and uninstalled Altiris. However, when I go to windows update, it keeps saying that "updated are managed by your system administrator".

So, I went into registry  HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft and removed WindowsUpdate entirely, where there were two values pointing to the company location for all updates. However, every time I login, it is recreated and software as System Center Endpoint protection keep appear gain (error when uninstalled).

I think this might be because of a statup script ( although I was not able to find one). Where can I find the script that causes this change, or at least, where is it usually placed?

Comment: Format and reinstall Windows - which should have been done before giving it to you. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to use group policy editor to manually deactivate automatic updates from the server.

The Fixit solves the problem temporary, but since this is caused by group policy editor, the registry is updated regularly with the external update server.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) contains a link to a microsoft "Fixit" which will reset your windows update component to its factory (online, windows only) state.  I've used this after dropping machines off of a WSUS/SCCM enabled domain before and its worked every time.

There are also "do it yourself" steps - hopwever I will not copy these across - there's loads of it!

Hope this helps.